# Why is finding the domain/range in inverse trig functions and normal functions the "opposite"?

Tags: functions, trigonometry

So I was doing this question: find the range of $y = 3\arcsin(2x+1)$. All you do is put the subject $y$ between the default range of $\arcsin \to -\frac{\pi}{2}\leq y \leq \frac{\pi}{2}$. So you start with $-\frac{\pi}{2} \leq \frac{y}{3} \leq \frac{\pi}{2}$ and make $y$ the subject.

But I remember for other functions, you actually can't do that. Rather you start with the *basic* range and work towards the given function. So for example, to find the range of $y = 4\cos(3x+2)$ you first need to know the domain of $y = \cos x \to -1 \leq y \leq 1$. Then you work towards $\frac{y}{4}$ ie times everything by a quarter. *This is unlike the "replacement" method used in inverse cos*. Why is that so?

Comment: Range is the possible values $y$ can take. You know the possible values $\cos(x)$ can take are between $1$ and $-1$. Now, $\frac{y}{4} = \cos(3x+2)$. What does that tell you about the possible values $\frac{y}{4}$ can take? Then what does that tell you about the possible values $y$ can take (I.e the range)?

Comment: It's the exact same logic you used with $\arcsin$, there is no difference.

Comment: $-1 \le \cos x \le 1$ is telling you the *range* of the cosine function, not the domain. The "domain" of a function consists of all values you that *put into* the function. The *range* is the set of all values that can *come out* of the function. The domain of $\arcsin$ is $-1$ to $1$. The range of $\arcsin$ is $-\frac \pi 2$ to $\frac \pi 2$. The domain of $\cos$ is all real numbers. The range of $\cos$ is $-1$ to $1$. The exact same method you used for $\arcsin$ will work for $\cos$ when you stop mixing up domain vs range.